# what is Program /46-0106 Error in node Veh1 on channel WLAN 1 in C2X IL CAPL function C2xGetTokenInt: Protocol "EU_ApplMsg::DENM" not found

Tags: vector, capl, canoe

I'm trying to write a counter which is sending a msg+CTR but when I'm running the program it's saying this type of error "Program / Model   46-0106 Error in node Veh1 on channel WLAN 1 in C2X IL CAPL function C2xGetTokenInt: Protocol "EU_ApplMsg::DENM" not found"
Please can anybody tell me what that error mean and how to fix it?

```
void OnC2xPacket( long channel, long dir, long radioChannel, long signalStrength, long signalQuality, long packet )
{
  byte  aRx_stationID;
  aRx_stationID = C2xGetTokenInt(packet, "DENM", "header.stationID");
  

  if(aRx_stationID == 222)
  {

    @Veh1::sVarRxDenmCounter = C2xGetTokenInt(packet, "DENM", "denm.situation.eventType.causeCode");
    if(@Veh1::sVarRxDenmCounter != gRxPacketCounterNew && gRxPacketCounterInit != 1) 
    {
      @Veh1::sVarLostPacketNumber++;
      @Veh1::sVarRecieveDataAge = 0;   
    }
    else
    {
      @Veh1::sVarRecieveDataAge =1;
    }
    gRxPacketCounterNew = ((@Veh1::sVarRxDenmCounter+1)%256);
    gRxPacketCounterInit = 0;
    if(@Veh1::sVarLostPacketNumber > 1000)
    {
      @Veh1::sVarLostPacketNumber =0;
    }    
  }
}
```

I used in the capl code the CAM and DENM messages to send Tx and receive Rx and in the capl code I don't have an error found but maybe there is an infinite loop or somebody else has a piece of knowledge about that issue.

Comment: Please show your code, post the complete error message and some information when exactly the error message occurs (during compile, runtime, ...)

Comment: Could you please show, how you register the callback. There should be a call to `C2xRegisterCallback` or `C2xReceivePacket` registering this `OnC2xPacket` somewhere in your code.